# How do I draw a scrollable background for an Android game

Tags: android, image, canvas, draw, android-bitmap

I want to draw an image that on some levels may be larger than the screen as the background for a Android game.  I want the user to be able to scroll the image using their finger on the touch screen.

Here is how I am drawing the background:

```
Bitmap scratch =  BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.background);
canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
canvas.drawBitmap(scratch, 0, 0, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`ImageView`](http://d.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) and put it in a [`ScrollView`](http://d.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) - I suspect this is not what you want though. If not, you're going to have to roll your own - take a look at the [GestureDetector](http://d.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html) for help with fling gestures.